# ng-repeat specify once json formatting

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In HTML:

```
<div class="field" ng-repeat="field in fields ">
    <strong>{{field.fieldName | json}}: {{field.itemCount | json}}</strong>
    <p ng-switch="field.type">
    <p ng-switch on="NUMBER">
    {{field.numberStats | json}}
    </p>
  </p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to specify `| json` just once somewhere and let the expression to be evaluated correctly?

thanks a lot

Comment: what is the need for using `json` filter in the first place? You generally only use that to display arrays or objects not for primitives

Comment: but I need to display objects properties that are objects themselves here... field.numberstats is 
{ "max": 1389691379, "mean": 1320206780, "min": 1389691322, "sum": 26404135609 }
and without `| json` it doesn't fit the div container

Comment: Is it really a problem to have the `| json` in a few places?

Comment: nope it's not, it just rings a bell when I have to use so many times the same command

Comment: well if you plan on showing json, you'll need to use it then. Any alternatives would require similar duplication

Answer (score 0):

`json` filter is not solution for style issues either worst. Redefine html structure better, as quick fix, try to change all `<p>` to `<div>`. **And also your markup is incorrect, `<p>` tag cannot nest**

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, nothing changes though